# Manually delete AUTOBACKUP of controlfile

Tags: delete, rman

My boss has decided to change retention policy to a 31 days period instead of redundancy of 4 copies.

One of the side effects is that autobackups get obsolete after 31 days.

This is the configuration of RMAN:

```
RMAN> show all;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name DBTEST are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 31 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
```

I have been trying to delete copies of controlfile older than 5 days but it always includes copies of controlfile in Level 0 and Level 1 backups not only autobackups.

If I try with `DELETE COPY OF CONTROLFILE LIKE '%F'` I do not get any file.

Is there any way to delete AutoBackup files which are stored on `+DGDATA/<dbname>/AUTOBACKUP/<date>/`?

Comment: If the official Retention Policy is 31 days, why do you want to remove files before the 31 day expiration?

Comment: I already have copies of controlfile with full and incremental backups. As every backup create a new copy and we backup archivelog every hour with new retention period I'll keep +20 copies of controlfile every day, that means +600 copies.

Comment: I believe that the cotrolfile is *part* of a backup.  As such, I feel that you need to retain them for 31 days also.

Comment: Autobackup is not necessarily part of backup. It is created automatically whenever a backup is done. But when you do an archivelog backup you are interested on archivelog.